# Reporting LRT(log likelihood ratios) from anova()

Tags: anova, item-response-theory, likelihood

I' ve got two logistic models/ based on IRT that I wanted to compare them using the log likelihoodratio test, so I used anova(model1, model2) in R. My output looks like following:

```
 Likelihood Ratio Table
            AIC      BIC   log.Lik   LRT df p.value
Model1 42470.30 42671.52 -21194.15                 
Model2 42057.51 42450.13 -20948.75 490.8 39  <0.001
```

How do I report these results in APA format?
Any help, or any information about where I could look it up would be super helpful.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: What models are you comparing here? You haven't provided any information about your fitted models, so we can't make any recommendations. To start though, try looking up the likelihood-ratio test first.

Comment: HI, thank you for responding. I am comparing two logistic based models, a  1 parameter logistic (1PL) and a 2 parameter logistic model (2PL). I am aware, that the results suggest that the 2PL fits better than the 1PL, given the AIC and p- value. I have tried to find out how to report LRTs in APA style, however, all my searches ended up showing me how to report chi- squares.

Comment: Did the author finally figured out, how to report results of LRTs? Curious if there is a recommended way?